# VBA MsgBox reformats dd/mm/yyyy Format output to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: vba, ms-access, vba7

Very new to VBA. I guess MsgBox debugging is the VBA equivalent to print statement debugging in other languages?

If I use `Format` to turn a date into a string using `dd/mm/yyyy` format, and then print that string with a MsgBox, it instead prints in `dd-mm-yyyy` format:

```vb
Function MsgBoxFormat()
    Const dt As Date = "2022-04-01"
    MsgBox (Format(dt, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
End Function
```

[image: Message box showing "01-04-2022"]

It only seems to do this for the results of the `Format` function and only if it uses `dd/mm/yyyy` formatting. Other formats and literal strings are not affected:

```vb
Function MsgBoxFormat()
    Const dt As Date = "2022-04-01"
    MsgBox ( _
        Format(dt, "dd/mm/yyyy") & vbNewLine & _
        Format(dt, "dd-mm-yyyy") & vbNewLine & _
        Format(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd") & vbNewLine & _
        Format(dt, "dd mmm yyyy") & vbNewLine & _
        "01/04/2022" _
    )
End Function
```

[image]

I'm a bit worried I've fundamentally misunderstood something about VBA here. Or could this be something obscure relating to my PC's locale settings?

This is VBA 7.1 running on an Access database.

Comment: Eh... `Debug.Print` is equal to other languages print statement debugging

Comment: Shouldn't be using parentheses after `MsgBox` here: it should be `MsgBox Format(dt, "dd\/mm\/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because "/" is not a slash but the local date separator. Use force:

```
MsgBox (Format(dt, "dd\/mm\/yyyy"))
```